# JSONException using selenium in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
```

I have added all the jars in my project but still can't get the solution to this problem

```
package automationFramework;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class FirstTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/Selenium/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.fb.com");
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.get("http://www.amazon.com\test\test");
        driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com");
        driver.get("http://www.snapdeal.com");
        driver.get("http://www.quora.com");
        driver.get("http://www.bebotechnologies.com");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### NoClassDefFoundError

[NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) in Java occurs when *Java Virtual Machine* is not able to find a particular *Class* at **runtime** which was available at **compile time**. For example, if we have resolved a method call from a class or accessing any static member of a *Class* and that *Class* is not available during run-time then *JVM* will throw *NoClassDefFoundError*.

The error you are seeing is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
```

This clearly indicates that Selenium is trying to resolve a particular *Class* at runtime from *org/json/JSONException*  which is no more available. At this point it is worth to mention calls to *Selenium* must be resolved from **org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver** (not from *org/json/JSONException*)

### Solution

Here are a few steps to solve **`NoClassDefFoundError`** :

- Remove all the **Selenium JARs** within your **Java Project** add only (single) latest version of [**Selenium JAR v3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) within the **Java Build Path**.
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Clean you **`Project Workspace`** within your *IDE* periodically only to build your project with required dependencies.
- Use **`CCleaner`** tool to wipe away the OS chores periodically.